# How to use Brant test with survey ordinal logistic reg (svyolr) to test PO assumption in complex survey data?

Tags: r, survey

I am using the R `survey` package to estimate an ordinal logistic regression on complex survey data using the function `svyolr()`.  I would like to test the proportional odds assumption with this weighted data, but `brant::brant()` only seems to work with unweighted models generated using `MASS::polr()`. Is anyone aware of how to test the PO assumption with a `svyolr` model?

Brant test reference using `brant::brant()` on a `MASS:polr()` model:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brant/brant.pdf
https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/166205/ThomasA_TheProportionalOddsModel.pdf?sequence=1

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are asking questions about how to test statistical modeling assumptions, it would be better to ask over at [stats.se] since that's really a statistical question.

Comment: This may be somewhat challenging because you've got to be able to relax the PO assumption e.g., with a generalized ordered logit model or a multinomial logit model neither is cleanly implemented in the survey context in R, though  check out [this package](https://github.com/carlganz/svrepmisc) for a survey-based MNL model.

Comment: @MrFlick Even though I am asking for an R implementation? Thanks!

Comment: If you were to describe completely the method you want to implement here with some test data and the desired result, then that might be sufficient to make it a programming question. Do you have an implementation for a different language? If no implementation exists anywhere currently, then it doesn't matter if you want R or anything other language. You need to figure out the method first. And most people on [stats.se] don't just do stats by hand. They are often very knowledgable about doing stuff in R as well.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the test has not been extended to survey data. The formulas in the original paper will not give a valid test with survey data, though it may be possible to extent the idea.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Brant's test relaxes the assumption by doing separate logistic regressions for the outcome variable dichotomised at each level rather than assuming these logistic regressions only differ in their intercepts.

Comment: @DaveAmstrong, also, the `svyVGAM` package does have both multinomial logit and generalised ordered logit.